# Activity title shows odd value

Tags: java, android, android-activity, layout, title

I have an activity that is based on the empty activity.  I have made a significant amount of changes to this but I haven't touched the activity title.  However, I have noticed that the title is now showing the word "White".  I have a second activity that contains the word white as the text of a button and some string resources that contain the word too.  However, I'm not sure how any of these are being picked up to display as the main activity title.  I've included a few relevant parts below.

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myfirstapp">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" android:required="false"/>

<application
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".DisplayDialogTextProperties"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Strings

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">MyFirstApp</string>
<string name="edit_message">Enter Text</string>
<string name="button_send">Apply Text</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="open_gallery">Open Gallery</string>
<string name="new_image">New Image</string>
<string name="OK">OK</string>
<string name="Cancel">Cancel</string>
<string name="Red">Red</string>
<string name="Blue">Blue</string>
<string name="Green">Green</string>
<string name="Black">Black</string>
<string name="White">White</string>
<string name="Yellow">Yellow</string>
<string name="Text_Properties_Colour">Choose the text colour you require</string>
<string name="Commit_Change">Commit Change</string>
<string name="Revoke_Change">Remove Change</string>

<!-- TODO: Remove or change this placeholder text -->
<string name="hello_blank_fragment">Hello blank fragment</string>
```

Activity onCreate method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    packageManager = getPackageManager();
   // getActionBar().setTitle("MyFirstApp");
}
</resources>
```

Activity Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
<!--tools:context="com.example.myfirstapp.MyActivity">-->

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:id="@+id/text_bar"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="false">
    <!--app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_my"-->

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message"
        android:enabled="false"/>

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:onClick="applyTextToImage"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:id="@+id/overlayButton"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttons_Layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/open_gallery"
            android:onClick="openGallery">
    </Button>

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/new_image"
            android:onClick="newImage">
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/image_Layout"
    android:layout_below="@id/text_bar"
    android:layout_above="@id/buttons_Layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
 >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_View"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
   <!--<TextView
        android:id="@+id/image_Overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"/>-->
</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Dialog Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/text_Properties"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:text="@string/Text_Properties_Colour"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/choose_Blue"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/text_Properties"
    android:onClick="btn_Click"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Blue"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/choose_Red"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/choose_Blue"
    android:layout_below="@id/text_Properties"
    android:onClick="btn_Click"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Red"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/choose_Green"
    android:layout_below="@id/text_Properties"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/choose_Blue"
    android:onClick="btn_Click"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Green"/>

<!--<TextView
    android:id="@+id/center_Point"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/choose_Blue"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>-->

<Button
    android:id="@+id/choose_Black"
    android:layout_below="@id/choose_Blue"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="btn_Click"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Black"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/center_Point_Lower"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/choose_Black"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/CommitChanges"
    android:onClick="commit_Click"
    android:text="@string/Commit_Change"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/choose_Black"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/center_Point_Lower"/>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/choose_Yellow"
    android:layout_below="@id/choose_Blue"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/choose_Black"
    android:onClick="btn_Click"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Yellow"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/choose_White"
    android:layout_below="@id/choose_Blue"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/choose_Black"
    android:onClick="btn_Click"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/White"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/CancelChanges"
    android:onClick="cancel_Click"
    android:text="@string/Revoke_Change"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/choose_Black"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/center_Point_Lower"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Styles

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Comment: 1. I also getting resources mess periodically, "Run"->"Rebuild project" helps me. 2. Also you forgot to post main xml layout, where `Toolbar` is defined 3. What shows in Title if you uncomment `getActionBar().setTitle("MyFirstApp")`?

Comment: I added that line in to try and resolve the issue.  It actually made the app crash which I think is due to something around the AppCompat version in use.

Comment: If youlre using support library, you need to call getSupportActionbar().setTitle()

Comment: Also I dont have a Main xml layout file only the one posted above and also a layout file for a dialog.  I can post this one but I dont know where the Toolbar is defined at the moment.

Comment: Please show your styles.xml

Comment: Styles looks good. Based on attached code there is no place where ActionBar title affected somehow. Please look into classes/layouts that aren't exist in your question.

Comment: I tried the project rebuild option suggested by Artem Mostyaev and the issue is now resolved.I think this was the solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per Artem's instructions Rebuild Project.